# How many persons can work simultaneousy on the same file which is added into Tortioise SVN repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How many persons can work simultaneousy on the same file which is added into Tortioise SVN repository?

Comment: Just remember to update before you commit.

Answer (score 2):

"Unlimited" and "one" are the correct answers. Let me explain detailfully.

#### Unlimited

because SVN is designed for collaborative development without imposing limits on the number of people that can contribute to development

#### One

because the only developer being able to commit modifications is the one who possesses the latest version of the file. Further modifications require **merging** previous modifications into current ones.

#### However, in practice

you would seriously organize your team in order for only small groups of people working on the same file simultaneously, or everyone commit only very small and simple modifications to shared files. This affects the number of required merge/conflict resolution operations.

Simple example: if you have a single global language file, you can allow every developer to add a few lines at the bottom of it without changing other lines. This translates into easy merging, since modifications are only "add lines"

Anyway, you sometimes may want to prevent people from simultaneously work on the same file by **locking** it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, any number of people can work on the file. The question comes when it's time to commit.

- If locked, only the person who locked the file can commit (and you should always check for a lock before editing a file)
- If not locked, everyone can commit (and sort out the merge conflicts later, once everyone decides to update)

A fair piece of information is in that Tortoise runs on the client and not on the server. Therefore unless you're using locks, the server will only ever be aware that you're working on the file when you choose to commit your changes.

Answer (score 0):

As many as you want. After one commits the file and a second updates the changes the file gets merged. If the first user altered something that the second also altered, the update will result in a conflict and the user will have see what's different from the local file to the one the first user altered and has to manually choose how the file should end up [see solving conflicts in tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html).

If the users modify different parts of the file then there's no issue to it and the file is merged on update.

Answer (score 0):

One, One and One.

Though Technically any number of users. you will soon find that yellow color CONFLICT is really a headache and will take more time to merge the code.

and i used svn a long time ago. it will be best if you can use Distributed Version Control like Git or Mercurial.